# How to simplify this algebraic expression? What is the proper name for this problem?

Tags: arithmetic

I am studying for a teacher exam and I am stumped with this problem $3\cdot \frac{(2+6)^2}{6}$

I know that the answer is $32$ because of the answer sheet, but how and why is this the answer? Can I get an example?

Comment: Where did you stuck ? Are you able to calculate $(2+6)^2$ ?

Comment: no I can not remember how to calculate this? its been awhile for me

Comment: OK, what is $2+6$ ?

Comment: Start by calculating $2+6$.

Comment: Hi I got the equation. I was squaring 8 instead of 7. It seems Like I had a brain fart. 2+6 is 7^2 is 49*3=147/6=32

Comment: No. $147/6=24.5$

Comment: 2+6 is 7^2=49*3=147/6=32. Do what's in parenthesis first

Comment: $6+2$ is not $7$.

Comment: sorry a typo 2+6 is 8 and 8 squared is 64. 64*3 is 192 and 192/6 is 32

Comment: Yes. But it might be easiert to first calculate the fraction of 3 and 6: $\frac{3}{6}$. Then take the intermediate result of 64 and multiply it by $\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$: $ \ \ $ $64\cdot \frac12=64/2=32$

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did find your way to the correct answer, so just to summarize one correct sequence of steps you could take to get there, we have (using the method that callculus described in a comment): $$3\cdot\frac{(2+6)^2}{6}=3\cdot\frac{8^2}{6}=3\cdot\frac{64}{6}=\frac{3}{6}\cdot64=\frac{1}{2}\cdot64=32$$